# Unable to load a model in pyspark and serve using grpc

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, grpc

I am trying to serve a spark wine classification model using grpc.

I have already trained the model. 
And I have already written the code to serve in on an http server using flask.

Now, I am trying to serve it using grpc to try and understand performance gains.

But I am getting the following error -

**Server Side -**

```
ERROR:root:Exception calling application: classify() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/dosi/Data/mlframework/venv/grpc/lib/python3.5/site-packages/grpc/_server.py", line 375, in _call_behavior
    return behavior(argument, context), True
TypeError: classify() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'
```

**Client Side -**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 20, in <module>
    run()
  File "client.py", line 16, in run
    proline=23.12))
  File "/media/dosi/Data/mlframework/venv/grpc/lib/python3.5/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 507, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, deadline)
  File "/media/dosi/Data/mlframework/venv/grpc/lib/python3.5/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 455, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNKNOWN, Exception calling application: classify() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context')>
```

I have the following doubt but I don't think that should be the cause of error -

- grpc is installed in a python virtual env. Maybe, while doing spark-submit I am not using the that virtual-env. I do not think this is the issue because in this case I should not be able to import grpc let alone launch the server and run the client.

**Server Code -**

```
import time, sys,  os
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
import config
import grpc
import wine_pb2
import wine_pb2_grpc
from concurrent import futures

_ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24

class WineClassifier(wine_pb2_grpc.WineClassifierServicer):

  def classify(self, request, context):
    return wine_pb2.WineClass(request.mg)

def init_spark_context():
    # load spark context
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("wine-app-server")
    # IMPORTANT: pass aditional Python modules to each worker
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
    .getOrCreate()

    return sc, spark


def run_server():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    wine_pb2_grpc.add_WineClassifierServicer_to_server(WineClassifier, server)
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')
    server.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(_ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Init spark context and load libraries
    sc, spark = init_spark_context()

    # start web server
    run_server()
```

**Proto file -**

```
syntax="proto3";

service WineClassifier {
  rpc classify (WineAttributes) returns (WineClass) {}
}

message WineAttributes {
    double alcohol = 1;
    double malic_acid = 2;
    double ash = 3;
    double alcalinity = 4;
    int32 mg = 5;
    double phenols = 6;
    double flavanoids = 7;
    double flavaniods = 8;
    double nf_phenols = 9;
    double proanthocyanins = 10;
    double color_intensity = 11;
    double hue = 12;
    double diluted = 13;
    double proline = 14;
}

message WineClass {
  int32 class = 1;
}
```

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: Are you able to share your `.proto` service definition and your server-side application code? It seems likely that you've implemented a method called "classify" that needs to have the signature `classify(request, servicer_context)` (or possibly `classify(request_iterator, servicer_context)`) but that you've actually coded as `classify(request)` (or `classify(request_iterator)`).

Comment: @NathanielManistaAtGoogle - I have updated the question please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that in `wine_pb2_grpc.add_WineClassifierServicer_to_server(WineClassifier, server)` you are passing the `WineClassifier` class object rather than an instance of the `WineClassifier` class. Try changing the line to `wine_pb2_grpc.add_WineClassifierServicer_to_server(WineClassifier(), server)`.

Comment: Thanks ! Silly me. But shouldn't this throw a meaningful error rather than unrelated missing "context" argument. Maybe, I am new to this hence I do not know it but that is kind of my point. Any new person getting into grpc will have the same problem. :/

Comment: That's a reasonable thought, but type errors like these are statically detectable and [Python is growing a static type system](https://github.com/google/pytype). Making type errors isn't particular to gRPC or to being new; it seems to be a foundational part of the human endeavour of crafting software. We _could_ put in some conditional checking in gRPC but it would probably do the wrong thing in the case of generic RPC handlers that aren't associated with generated code elements. I think the right thing to do is to let type errors like these be solved like all others: by a static type system.